# Addition turns into concatenation

Tags: javascript

```
var Height=  (rowData.length * 30) + PPPP.top + 10 ;
```

When i print this i get 9013510... instead of 90 +135+10 = 235. Why does mine turns into concatentaion instead of Addition.

Comment: Is PPPP.top a string, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably treating one of the values incorrectly as a string.  Try using parseInt and see if that works:

```
var Height=  (rowData.length * 30) + parseInt(PPPP.top, 10) + 10;
```

Comment: haha, yes, maybe overkill!  In fact as everyone else spotted it's really just the PPPP.top value that requires parseInt

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to convert PPPP.top to a number, eg.

```
var Height = (rowData.length * 30) + parseFloat(PPPP.top) + 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

`PPPP.top` is probably a string. Try:

```
var Height=  (rowData.length * 30) + parseInt(PPPP.top, 10) + 10 ;
```

Comment: +1 for specifying the radix when calling [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 1):

You can use parseInt for that.

```
var Height=  (rowData.length * 30) + parseInt(PPPP.top, 10) + 10 ;
```

I have changed radix to base 10.

Comment: parseInt should always be given the radix parameter if you want to avoid something like a user's input of 08 being turned into 0

Comment: Yes, Thanks. But you know when validation will come into play we have to make sure that everything is ok. Here I just gave the hint how can you handle it. There could be many ways how you want your user input the value.